# Cannot install VLC on Windows 8, I'm getting the error: A referral was returned from the server

Tags: windows-8, vlc-media-player

I'm having an issue while installing VLC in Windows 8 (upgraded from Windows 7). I keep receiving the error: `A referral was returned from the server` when I'm trying to install the application. 
I tried to run it as administrator and I get the same error.

I ran `sfc /scannow` and it didn't discover any corrupted Windows files.

Can somebody help me out with this problem.

Comment: This sounds like their installer downloads some content and the installer is unable to contact the server in question.

Comment: Well I verified my internet connection and everything is working fine...

Comment: Did you verify my theory?  Have you verified if the installer attempts to connect to the internet and download additional files?

Comment: I'll check tonight, I think that it is connecting to internet, but why is it giving this error and how can I fix it ? If I use the same installer on my office computer, with the same hardware and OS, I don't have the issue.

Comment: Confirm the theory.  Based on the information you provided I would only be guessing at the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, I was having problem because I deactivated UAC and the VLC is not signed and validated.

Here how to fix this problem:

1. Run `gpedit.msc` from the start menu.
2. Go to `Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security Options`.
3. Change the value of `User Account Control: Only elevate executables that are signed and validated` from `Enabled` to `Disabled`.

[Source of this solution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4RdNv-bywE) (youtube video)